Unreal engine: Landscape + Water body ocean
I’m encountering a visual artifact while adding landscape and water body ocean with default settings. The issue is that the water above the terrain appears to be disconnected from the rest of the ocean and is displayed at a higher level than the rest of the ocean surface. I’ve attached a screenshot for reference. Can you provide any insights on how to resolve this problem?

Any answer?  I am having the same issue in UE5.4
